# Убрать в конце url имя файла

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть ссылки вида: `www.site.com/nazvanie_url/teheme`, где "theme" - это название файла.

Помогите избавится от названия без ущерба для поиска при индексировании (я про редирект).

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот так:

```htaccess
RewriteEngine On

Options +MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Или в крайнем случае можешь вот так на PHP написать:

```php
if(stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php")){
    $currentPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $shortCut = str_replace(".php", "", $currentPage);
    header("Location:".$shortCut);
}
```

Тогда оно будет жестоко обрезать запрашиваемый URL и сразу же перенапправлять на страницу без `.php`. В данном случае параметр `Options +MultiViews` в .htaccess обязателен.

### Но это все херня! Вот реальный ответ, что тебе нужно

Возьму на примере своего сайта: у меня в корне, где лежит главная сайта (то есть index.php) есть папка CSS, в корой находятся все CSS файлы. И если у меня поддиректория по путь выглядит так: `../css/путь_к_нужной_папке`. Если тебе надо например сделать как ты написал в комментариях, то у тебя должно быть так:

```html
RewriteRule ^mobile_samsung?$ mobile_samsung/product [NC,L]
```

И например в файле `product.php` у тебя путь к файлам был `../file/path`, тогда в этом случае убери в этом файле `../` и все работает норм. А если у тебя `../../` то поэксперементируй с этими `../` пока не заработает. Причина: файл находился в одной субдиректории, а ты его с помощью  `.htaccess` перенес в другую директорию, и вот все ссылки поломались.

Comment: мне не php обрезать надо, а название файла

Из сайт.ру/юрл/файл.пхп   сделать  сайт.ру/юрл

Comment: @Vladislav_Carley  Ааа, Ок я понял. Но как я понимаю ты в папке `юрл ` не хочешь создавать файл `index.php`. Я правильное понимаю?

Comment: еще немного и я сам запутаюсь)))  Смотри, есть ссылки вида https://site.com/mobile_samsung/product  где product это файл product,php который и показывает товар по ссылке mobile_samsung.

Нужно убрать product и сделать что бы было так https://site.com/mobile_samsung

Comment: @Vladislav_Carley  Понял. Ща попробую предложить вариант.

Comment: в штакесе только вот это  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/product$ /product.php?url=$1 [L]

Кста RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]  не работает!

Comment: @Vladislav_Carley Ну вот сюда в первую ссылку можешь написать, что захочешь, но все подключенные файлы уйдут к черту `RewriteRule ^mobile_samsung?$ mobile_samsung/product [NC,L]` А так сорян, ничего больше не могу предложить.

Comment: хз  мертвая романтика...  Может пхп или скрипт может справится с этим?

Comment: @Vladislav_Carley Дполнил решение.